# How do I print just the even or odd chars in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Lets say I have string: 'firetruck'. And I split that string up into the individual letters and put them into an array called T for example. So now T[] looks like {f,i,r,e,t,r,u,c,k}. How can I just print the even chars so my print statement looks like 'frtuk' and the odd looks like 'ierc'. This is what I got so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class StringFun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String even_odd = sc.next();
        char[] t = even_odd.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));

        //I can't get this next part to work.
        for(int i = t[0]; i < t.length; i = i + 2){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a minor mistake in the code:

You don't need the *first value from the array* to initialize the loop variable `i`, just the *index value* you want the loop to start from.

One tricky thing to keep in mind is that the indexing starts from 0, but we, humans count from 1. <sub>(I did a mistake with this in the first edit of the answer too)</sub> So the characterss with **even** ordinals will be printed when the start value is **odd**.

The start of indexing is quite a common issue one has to constantly keep in mind...

Also, you can print characters directly, you don't need the [Arrays.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28char%5B%5D%29) method here:

```
System.out.println(t[index]);
```

Is enough.

**Odd chars:** set `i` to 0: this will print the 1st, 3rd ... characters

```
       for(int i = 0; i < t.length; i = i + 2){
            System.out.println(t[i]);
        }
```

**Even chars:** set `i` to 1: this will print the 2nd, 4th ... chars

```
       for(int i = 1; i < t.length; i = i + 2){
            System.out.println(t[i]);
        }
```

#### Eliminating the array

Also, you don't even need to create a char array, you could use [String.charAt(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) for this purpose:

```
        String even_odd = sc.next();

        for(int i = 0; i < even_odd.length(); i = i + 2){
            System.out.println(even_odd.charAt(i));
        }
```

#### Taking it to the next level

Also, to be extra nice, you could extract this into a function, and **reuse** the functionality:

```
private static void printChars(String input, boolean even) {
        int i = 0;
        if(even) { //if we need the even chars, start from 1;
          i=1;
        }
        for(; i < input.length(); i = i + 2){
            System.out.println(input.charAt(i));
        }
}
```

And then your main method would be just this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String even_odd = sc.next();
        char[] t = even_odd.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));

        //calling the function for even numbers
        printChars(even_odd, true);

        //calling the function for odd numbers
        printChars(even_odd, false);
    }
```

**Remember** duplication is **bad**. **Reuse --> good**.

Answer (score 3):

Start your loop with `0` instead of `t[0]`

```
 for(int i = 0; i < t.length; i = i + 2){
```

Currently `i` will hold `102` which is ASCII value of letter `f`, and it will not enter in the loop because of the condition.

Why `i` will hold a `char` value, for that see [Widening primitive conversion - Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) which allows

> char to int, long, float, or double

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple.  Just put in an `if(i % 2 == 0)` to determine whether or not to print the character.

Also, there's no need for the `Arrays.toString(t[i])`.  Change that to just `t[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Odd

```
 char[] arr={'f','i','r','e','t','r','u','c','k'};
 for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     if(i%2==1){
         System.out.print(arr[i]);
     }
 }
```

Out put

```
 ierc
```

Even

```
   char[] arr={'f','i','r','e','t','r','u','c','k'};
   for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(i%2==0){
     System.out.print(arr[i]);
     }
    }
```

Out put

```
 frtuk
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small error! You were close. This should fix it.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < t.length; i = i + 2){
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on the for statement, is not int i = t[0] but should be int i = 0; otherwise it will take the ASCII value of the character on the dirt position of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through your string and print out what you want.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String even_odd = sc.next();

    System.out.println("Odd Characters");
    for(int i = 0; i<even_odd.length(); i++){
        if(i%2==0){
            System.out.println(even_odd.charAt(i));
        }   
    }

    System.out.println("Even Characters");
    for(int i = 0; i<even_odd.length(); i++){
        if(i%2==1){
            System.out.println(even_odd.charAt(i));
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You should maybe explain to him why it will do that

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
public class char_odd_even {

    public static void main(String arg[]){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s;
        s = sc.next();

        char char_array[];

        char_array=s.toCharArray();
        int a[] = new int[char_array.length];

        for(int i=0;i<char_array.length;i++)
        {
            a[i]=s.charAt(i);

            if(a[i]%2==0){
                System.out.println((char)a[i]+" EVEN CHAR " + a[i]);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println((char)a[i]+" ODD CHAR " + a[i]);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: There is already a vert detailed accepted answer. You answer doesn't add anything new.

Answer (score 0):

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

```
/**
 * 
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. 
     * Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int totalStrings = scanner.nextInt();

    String nextString = null;
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        nextString = scanner.next();
        int stringsCount = totalStrings;
        Solution stringInterleaving = new Solution();
        int startIndexEven=0,incrementEven=2;
        int startIndexOdd=1,incrementOdd=2;
         int printedCharCountEven = 0;
        int printedCharCountOdd = 0;
        if(nextString!=null && nextString.length()>0) {
             printedCharCountEven =
                stringInterleaving.printChars(nextString, startIndexEven,incrementEven);
               if(printedCharCountEven>0) {
                 System.out.print(" ");
               }
            printedCharCountOdd =
                stringInterleaving.printChars(nextString, startIndexOdd,incrementOdd);
        }
        if(printedCharCountEven>0 || printedCharCountOdd>0) {
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
    if(scanner!=null) {
        scanner.close();   
    }
}

    /**
 * 
 * @param input
 */
private int printChars(String input,int startIndex,int increment) {
        int printedCharCount = 0;
        if(input!=null && input.length()>0) {
            for(int i=startIndex;i<input.length();) {
               System.out.print(input.charAt(i));
                i=i+increment;
                printedCharCount++;
            }
        }  
    return printedCharCount;
}
```

}